# Layout corrupted in ADF projects

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm working on some projects on Jdeveloper 11.1.1.2.0 IDE and encounter an annoying problems. The layout of jspx pages corrupted, all control attached to any page disappear without a trace when running project. They dont show in design tab either. The problem appears suddenly when I modify some page.

Now I cant working on the project and have to restart project from scratch. So if you have encountered and fixed the same problem. Could you please show me how to do it. I'm very grateful to hear any suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't allow any educated guess on what happens. Can you at least paste the page source that you encounter the problem with ?

Often issues like this occur by developers placing the content to a facet that is not made for this and that does not stretch. Or if the a tag is not closed properly or missing (the page source editor should flag this)

Before starting from scratch, which should not bee needed at all, try JDeveloper 11.1.2.2 to reproduce it in a later build.

Comment: Thank you Nimphius. I will try to create same problems like this in a test application using your suggestion and see if can do anything to fix it. I found a backup of this project and removed the failed one, Currently the backup one is working fine.